# Is it possible to emulate the firmware of ereader devices?

Tags: kindle, kobo, nook, firmware, tolino

I'd like to know if it is possible to emulate the firmware of the various available ereader devices, and run them from a personal computer.

I'd like to know this mainly to try and compare them and see all of their features in action.

***NOTE***: My interest is not limited to the brands that I've used for tagging this questions, it is just the limit of five tags.

Answer (score 3):

It'd theoretically possible, but no device manufacturer (except for Amazon) bothered to develop and release emulators.

If you want to make sure that your epubs look OK on each device, you might want to check them with the desktop versions of [Adobe Digital Editions](http://www.adobe.com/solutions/ebook/digital-editions/download.html), because all major eInk manufactures, except for Amazon, ship with an app that uses the same rendering engine. (All eInk device manufacturers that offer [ADEPT DRM support](https://blogs.adobe.com/aemmobile/supported-devices) are required to include [RMDSK](http://www.adobe.com/solutions/ebook/rmsdk.html)-based ePub apps, because no other ePub app will open ADEPT DRM-protected ebooks.)

Comment: Thank you; I was more interested about this from a user perspective, to compare the feature of the various ereaders, not strictly to check how ebooks are displayed; upvoted nonetheless, it is still a good answer.